# Breakpoints and the 'font-size' parameter

Tags: media-queries, breakpoints, compass-sass, font-size, susy-compass

Has anyone had any experience of using the 'font-size' parameter with the at-breakpoint mixin?

In the documentation it states the following...

```
    <$font-size>: When using EMs for your grid, the font size is important. Default: $base-font-size
```

In a design I am working with I am taking the mobile first approach so the $base-font-size = 12px.

I am then adding a breakpoint at 50em's (arbitrary value for this example) as follows...

```
    @include at-breakpoint(50em 12, 16px) {
      .container{
        @include container;
      }
    }
```

I'm not sure if I have got the understanding of this correctly but I was expecting, given that I've specified a value for 'font-size', that my font size would increase to 16px once the screen exceeded 50em.

However, I think I might have got the wrong end of the stick as to the purpose of this 'font-size' parameter as the font size remains at 12px at any size.

Does anyone know what this parameter affects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that feature is not well documented. It is not there to set a font size, but to fix em-based media-queries. If you are using a base font-size of `12px`, this is very important.

Browsers always interperet em-based media-queries relative to the default browser font size (16px). It doesn't make any sense at all, but that's how they do it. So, in order for you to make a breakpoint at 50em (*12px), we have to set the breakpoint at 37.5em (*16px, the browser default). Passing your base font-size allows us to make that adjustment.

This should be better documented, and the argument should be better named. I've created an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues/115).

Comment: Thanks Eric, that explains it perfectly. Great work you've done with Susy by the way, I'm enjoying working with it.